# Inno Setup: Create simplified ComponentsList

Tags: inno-setup, pascalscript

I have only two components for a user to choose from when installing.  Neither depends on each other, and none has any constraints.  I’d like to present two simple checkboxes with no extra layout, instead of the complexity of `TNewCheckListBox` (i.e. `ComponentsList`).  Is there a way to do this?

Here's an image of what I'm after:

[image]

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I've added a link .. unfortunately, I couldn't put the link in the image format because of my reputation .. when/if it goes >= 10, I'll re-edit as an image link.

Comment: Thank for editing and adding the image, Martin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what you mean by "complexity". If it's just about the list looking as a list box, what about styling it not to look like a list?

```pascal
procedure InitializeWizard();
begin
  WizardForm.ComponentsList.BorderStyle := bsNone;
  WizardForm.ComponentsList.ParentColor := True;
  WizardForm.ComponentsList.Top := WizardForm.SelectComponentsLabel.Top;

  WizardForm.ComponentsDiskSpaceLabel.Visible := False;
  WizardForm.SelectComponentsLabel.Visible := False;
end;
```

[image]

Comment: This is great!  Together with `WizardForm.ComponentsDiskSpaceLabel.Visible := False;` and
`WizardForm.SelectComponentsLabel.Visible := False;` your suggestions get me 99% what I want.  Thanks!